# Obtaining refresh_token through offline_access scope to be used with IAP

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth, refresh-token, google-iap

I am using IAP to protect a Web API Application. I have enabled a service account to get access to the APIs through an `id_token`. I am able to obtain an `id_token` (JWT) by signing a JWT (using the keys of my service account) with the following assertions

```
{
  "iss": "xx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "xx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "target_audience": "my_application_client_id",
  "iat": 1598702078,
  "exp": 1598705593
}
```

and then Posting to the token service as follows

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'assertion=<JWT obtained at the previous step>’
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid’
```

Now I would like to also obtain a refresh_token and has been impossible. I have tried with `scope=openid offline_access` but no luck. Is `offline_access` implemented in the Google Auth Server? Any other mechanism to obtain a refresh_token?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#exchangecode), for the OpenID server flow you would need to use `access_type` as parameter set to offline for it to work. There are more details [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline).